# cacti - issue on using one graph template for different devices

Tags: graph, cacti

I created a bash script to get the disk usage of a linux ubuntu server. After that, I created a graph template (using the data source which contains the bash script to get the disk usage of a server). Then I created 2 different devices which points to different servers.

It automatically created 2 graphs based on the devices I created. Something like this:

`Server 1 - Disk Usage`
`Server 2 - Disk Usage`

After I placed the graphs on different trees, I noticed that they have the same disk usage.

`Server 1`:

[image]

`Server 2`:

[image]

As you can see, they both have 20%. But in reality, only `Server 1` is 20%. `Server 2` should be 14%. It's like the graph for `Server 2` is using the output of the script intended for `Server 1`, and not getting the output of the script for `Server 2`. Can someone tell me a possible workaround or solution for this? I'm only new to cacti so it's a bit hard for me to understand how this works.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was told that a bash script will only be run on the cacti server, and not on remote servers.

https://github.com/Cacti/cacti/issues/3458